# How to call a function within another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created nested function in one script file A.js, like below:

```
function A(){
   function B(){}
}
```

If I want to call function B() in another script file C.js, what should I do?

Comment: Is there any reason for the nested function? Is there anything else in function A, or is it just function B?

Comment: How you would do that depends on many other things. There is no one right answer.

Comment: You can't, you cannot access another function's scope, unless you expose it.

Comment: This is like a function closure. You need to somehow return `B` from `A()`. Longer answer coming up!

Comment: This may help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: If you need it elsewhere and it doesn't depend on its containing function, lift that function to the top level.

Comment: @Andy , there's sth else in function A,  A is kind of a general function, B is a specific function for one functionality, it belongs to A in a general logic sense, so I put it inside A. but I also need to call B once in C.js, so here comes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do seems to be to create a [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) of `B` using the variables within `A()`. You can then access this closure `B` if you return `B` after you call `A()`. Then, in `C.js`, you can access `B` by calling `A` and using the return value:

`A.js`:

```
function A([parameters]) {
    [variables]
    function B() { [function body] }
    //Return B from A:
    return B;
}
```

`C.js`:

```
//Get B:
var bFunction = A([parameters]):
//Call bFunction:
bFunction();
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need~

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the nested function:

```
function A(){
   return function B(){}
}
```

Then In C.js

```
var funB = A();
funB();
```

or

```
A()();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the nested function `B()` from the parent function `A()`.

Your code

```
function A(){
   function B(){}
}
```

Updated Code with return statement

```
function A(){
    return function B(){ //return added

 }     
 }
```

You can access the child function by adding an additional `()` Parentheses to the function call like the below example.

```
A()();
```